# how to use PMCMD command in UNIX

Tags: unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter

how to use **pmcmd** command in UNIX script. am not able to execute directly in shell script it is not executing.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: when i type $pmcmd in UNIX terminal am getting as ksh: pmcmd: not found.

Comment: You need to find where Informatica PowerCenter is installed on the server, and set that path in $PATH variable

Answer (score 1):

First you should set the informatica bin directory in PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH  in .bashrc as below

```
PATH=/<YourInformaticaHome>/server/bin:$PATH 
export PATH 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/<YourInformaticaHome>/server/bin: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then you could run pmcmd command in shell script.

Comment: how to get to know informatica path in unix server using powercenter client tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below syntax to execute workflows.

```
pmcmd startworkflow -sv Integration_Service_Name -d Domain_Name -u User_Name -p Password -f Folder_Name Workflow_Name
```

No need of script. You can directly execute in command line. If you still need a script, save the command in a .sh file and execute it

Comment: am not able to run directly because PMCMD is in different path(i don't know what is the issue exactly)

Comment: Just type PMCMD in your unix terminal, it will get into its utility. Try doing that. Once done, just execute startworkflow **-sv Integration_Service_Name -d Domain_Name -u User_Name -p Password -f Folder_Name Workflow_Name**

Comment: when i type **$pmcmd** in UNIX terminal   am getting as **ksh: pmcmd: not found.**

Comment: You have to run this command from informatica server --> bin directory. Switch to this directory and run the command or export the path in unix terminal and run the command

Comment: when i try to run am getting following errors : 0509-036,0509-150,0509-022,**0509-026 : system error : the file  access permission do not allow the specified action.**

Comment: You have executing access in the environment. If not contact your administrator

Comment: is there any way i can run a script in command task (**Informatica workflow manager**), which is recursive

Comment: You no need a command task for this. PMCMD is an informatica utility that can be used in unix terminal if the home path is set an if you have execute permissoins